# What does min_depth in ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config do?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection-api

In Tensorflow's object detection API, [ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config) file has min_depth parameter. Now it is set to 16.

Is it minimum network length set to 16?

If I change to lower value, will the network length be shorter?
What layers will be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Multi-resolution feature maps]

This parameter stands for the minimum depth of each of the output feature maps produced by the feature extractor.  As we know SSD use multi-resolution feature maps to help detect objects of multiple scales. Changing it to a smaller value won't necessarily make the depth shorter as the depth is also controlled by the `depth_multiplier` as shown in [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/models/feature_map_generators.py#L33). So for each extra feature layer as shown in the figure, the two parameter will control the depth of it. More details are specified in class [KerasMultiResolutionFeatureMaps](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/models/feature_map_generators.py#L49) and function [`multi_resolution_feature_maps`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/models/feature_map_generators.py#L268)